# How to obtain the number of real valued zeroes of a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

While I know there's no analytical formula for the roots of a general polynomial of degree five and higher, I wonder whether there is at least something like a parabola's discriminant to determine how many of the roots are real-valued?

Comment: a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SturmFunction.html

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Thanks, I'm no native speaker, that's interesting to finally learn

Comment: @JackD&#39;Aurizio Thanks, that seems to perfectly answer my question, doesn't it?

Comment: @WillJagy A good start indeed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Descartes rule of signs could help very well. The intermediate value theorem can be used as well.

Since a polynomial is continous at every point in the real-number system. You can use the intermediate value theorem on an interval,

[a, b] such that if f(a) < 0 and f(b) > 0 , there is a point x = c in (a, b) such that f(c) = 0.